# Handling spatial join 10 chars field name limit

Tags: qgis, spatial-join

When I try to perform a spatial join between a point and polygon file, I get a notice saying spatial join will not be performed because following field names exceed 10 Characters.

How do I rectify this?

Answer (score 11):

This is the limitation of Shapefile format that the field name must be less than 10 characters. You can install the plugin 'Table Manager' and rename the fields using the plugin ( Plugins -> Table -> Table Manager ) so the length is less than 10 characters and then try the join again.