# QGIS Spatial Queries

Tags: qgis, attribute-table

I was wondering if I could do the following within QGIS:

I want to update a column in my point layer with the attribute information from a specific column in a polygon layer - so I have a layer of postcodes and I want to give it a column of say School Catchment and I want to populate this column with the value of the school name column in the catchment area polygon layer.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Steve

Comment: Try use QGIS 'Vector -> Data Management Tools -> Join attributes by location' tool - in point layer added attributes from polygonal layer using spatial join.

Comment: I have tried that and it seems to restrict the length of column names for me, stating that certain field names are longer than 10 characters..

Comment: some info about length of field http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/27342/how-to-handle-spatial-join-10-chars-field-name-limit

Comment: ah ok that makes sense, but I've found 'Point Sampling Tool' which does just what I need it to. It let's me pick specific columns, and from multiple tables in one process!!!

Answer (score 1):

I found a tool called Point Sampling Tool that does just what I need it to. It allows me to select specific columns, from multiple polygon layers and in one process produces for me a look-up table to show all of the boundaries a specific point falls within!!!